# Using word2vec for supervised classification

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, supervised-learning

I am trying to use word2vec for supervised classification of labelled classes. I have data containing sentences with their labels which I would like to train the word2vec model on, and then use word2vec (or possibly random forest classifier) in order to figure out the classes of unseen sentences. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import gensim
import numpy as np

class TokenizedSentence(object):

    def __init__(self, doc_list):
            self.doc_list = doc_list

    def __iter__(self):
            for t in (self.doc_list):
                    t = t.decode('utf-8')
                    yield gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(t)



tweets = ["a tweet", "another tweet", ... , "some tweet"]
labels = [1, 1, ... , 16]

training_data = TokenizedSentence(tweets)

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(training_data, size=150, window=10, min_count=2, workers=10)
model.train(training_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=200)
model.save("w2vmodel")
```

I am wondering how I need to go about doing this in order to include the labels that go along with each sentence, so that I can tell the model which label a sentence belongs to, and then be able to load the model in a separate file and classify unseen data into categories based on the supervised learning. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds to me like you want Doc2Vec rather than word2vec if you want to cluster collections of words such as sentences or tweets.